# google chrome ubuntu 16.04 render bug

Tags: google-chrome

I always have the kind of rendering bug on google chrome on my ubuntu 16.04, anyone knows why and how to solve it?

[image: bug]

I can see this bug everywhere, on the menu, on some text of a page, etc. And this happens just etremely often. But on firefox, there is no such kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It goes away after I turn off hardware acceleration

Steps to turn off

1. At url bar type chrome://settings/
2. Scroll down to `System` section (click `Advanced` to show this)
3. Turn off "Use hardware acceleration when available"

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this, enter following URL in the google chrome browser

[chrome://settings](http://chrome://settings)

Settings > Appearance

Check on **Use system title as a border**

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Have you tried press Alt+Space unmaximise?

Comment: No, I haven't done that.